# yet another redirect after form submit

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve this: 
php form. jquery formsubmit. when form is submitted - user is being redirected
The code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#submit').click(function(e){ 
    $("form").submit();
    window.location.href = '<?=$http_path?>/usr/checkout_invoice';
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; });

});
```

It either submits the code (when the redrect is off) or redirects but never does two things as intended.

what am I missing????

**Update**

OKay. Good fellow below suggested to use AJAX. Here is teh solution (that worked) for those who are interested:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#shipping_ok').bind('click touchstart', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var city =  $('#city').val();
        var province =  $('#province').val();
        var zip =  $('#zip').val();

        $.ajax({    
           type : 'POST',
           url : '<?=$http_path?>/usr/ja.php',
           data: {city : city,province : province,zip : zip},
           success : function(data){
               window.location.href = '<?=$http_path?>/usr/checkout_invoice';
           },
           error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
               alert ("Error Occured");
           }
        });
        return false; 
   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: A form submit is a request to whatever URL is specified in the form's `action` attribute, and it causes the browser to show whatever response comes back from that request. (If no action is specified it submits to the current page.) So that behaviour is likely clashing with your attempt to set the `location.href`, which is a different kind of page request.

Comment: action is SELF
but.. looks like your suggestion is true...
gotta re-work it with ajax then (hmm.. if THAt will work)...

Comment: Submit by ajax and set `location.href` from within your ajax success handler.

Comment: post this as your answer please

Comment: I bet if you googled this you would find an answer... even if you search SO

Comment: @Seabizkit what is the purpose of this site then?

Comment: @Rossitten sorry don't take it the wrong way. I google what you asked for another reason and it come up with two links to SO, answering basically same question. Just saying if you googled what you asked you would have found an answer, instead of asking the same question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some background as to why it does not work.**

Form submits are Post backs to the server, they will reload the page... (usually the same URL)

As javascript is bond to the page, when you submit the form, a request to the server is made an a response will be returned.

At this point it is starting to replace the current page with the new response page.

The new response page will known nothing about what happen before.

This will reload the javascript and effectively null out any javascript,
which was executing or going to be executed on the page.

so...

```
$("form").submit();
//page is reloaded from server... loosing content of any javascript.

//anything below wont happen
---------------------
//window.location.href = '<?=$http_path?>/usr/checkout_invoice';
```

The javascript window location will not happen... as the page is being reloaded, by time it is reloaded,
    it is unaware that the page was in a javascript function... so the redirect wont happen.

Comment: Thank you mate. well explained and, yea... that was, probbaly, quite easy to Google (even though I tried to find answer here first with no luck).

Comment: @Rossitten np i thought as much, been there too ;-) all good.